# Exponential random variable is almost surely finite

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $T$ be a random variable with $Exp(\lambda)$ distribution for $\lambda >0$.

I want to show that $T < \infty$ a.s.

In order to do that, we need to show that $P(T < \infty) =1$.

So I thought of different ways of proving that but as I am not that good with limits and continuous distributions, I am a little bit confused.

1) So my first idea was to show that 
$$P(T \leq t)= 1- e^{- \lambda t} \underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 1,$$
but I am not sure whether this implies that
$P(T \leq \infty)=1$ or $P(T < \infty)=1$. If only the first one, then this property is trivial.

2) My second idea was to work with $P(T > t)=e^{-\lambda t}$. If for every fixed $t$ we have $P(T > t) = e^{-\lambda t}$, then when $t \rightarrow \infty$ we have $$P(T = \infty) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(T > t)= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} e^{-\lambda t} = 0,$$
but again I am not sure (and it is somehow basically the same as in 1)).

So can you help me by telling me what $P(T=\infty)$ means expressed in terms of $P(T\leq t)$?

**My guess?**

So is $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(T > t) = P(T = \infty)$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} P(T \leq t) = P(T < \infty)$? Is that true? Are these also the same events?

Thank you very much and please excuse the stupid questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we have
$$ \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \{T \le n\} = \{T < \infty\}$$
as $T(\omega) < \infty$ for $\omega \in \Omega$ iff $T(\omega) \le n$ for some $n \in \def\N{\mathbf N}\N$. Now, by the so called continuity of the measure, we have
$$ P(\{T \le n\}) \to P(\{T < \infty\})$$
To prove that, write 
\begin{align*}
  P(T < \infty) &= P\left(\{T \le 0\} \cup \bigcup_{n \in \N} (\{T \le n+1\} - \{T \le n\})\right)\\
   &= P(T\le 0) + \sum_{n\in\N} P(\{T \le n+1\} - \{T \le n\})\\
   &= P(T\le 0) + \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} P(T \le k+1) - P(T\le k)\\
   &= \lim_{n\to \infty} P(T \le n)
\end{align*}
Taking complements, we have $P(T > n) \to P(T = \infty)$.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. This was extremely helpful and exactly what I am was looking for. Moreover, it is written in such a way that I am able to understand these things (as a non-mathematician). Thank you very much!! That helped a lot!

Comment: I read your answer and was really convinced. But now I am asking myself: Does this really work for continuous random variables?

Comment: Yes, it does. The argument does not make any assumptions on $T$ besides being a random variable.

Comment: Could I ask you what it means to have $\{T \leq n+1\} - \{T \leq n\}$ in the first line above? It seems that each is an event so I am not sure what you mean by the difference of events.

Comment: @user321627 It is the usual set difference, 
$$ A - B = \{x \in A : x \not\in B\}$$

Comment: @martini Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, since the set $\{T \leq n\}$ is non-decreasing, does it automatically hold from set-theoretic limits that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \{T \leq n\}= \bigcup_{j \geq 1} \{T \leq n\} = \{T < \infty\}$ or is there something deeper I am missing? Also sorry to ask but is the exponential memoryless property somehow invoked here? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If $P\{X=+\infty\}>0$ then $P\{X<+\infty\}<1$.

Then $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}F_X(t)=1$ implies that for some $t\in \mathbb R$ we have $P\{X\leq t\} >P\{X<+\infty\}$ contradicting that $\{X\leq t\}\subseteq\{X<+\infty\}$.